# Responsive navbar with dropdown mobile hamburger icon disappears when toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

The drop-down menu works fine on the laptop.
On the mobile device it comes up as a single bar. When I select the hamburger icon, the drop-down are displays as they should. When I select one of the buttons, the link works. But if I instead hit the hamburger icon the second time, the hamburger and complete bar disappear. The only way to bring the navbar back is to do a browser refresh.

I have tried several responsive navbar code selections and this is the closest to a working responsive navbar.

HTML code
...

```
      <nav>
            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="PlanYourVisit.php">New Here</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Ministries
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="Ministries_Adult.php">Adult</a>
                        <a href="Ministries_Care.php">Member Care</a>
                        <a href="Ministries_Outreach.php">Outreach</a>
                        <a href="Ministries_Youth.php">Youth</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="Giving.php">Donate</a>
```

...

```
        <a href="ContactUs.php">Contact</a>
        <a href="AboutUs.php">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="navBarIcon()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS code
...

```
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

...
javascript code

```
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
function navBarIcon() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

As I mentioned, the code works except when the hamburger icon is hit a second time to close the navbar. It goes beyond closing, but rather disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Modified javascript and it works now.

```
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon */
function navBarIcon() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```